# In Android when I Try to Change from a Fragment View to an Activity Via a Button the XML View of the Activity Changes to Linear from Absolute View?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Below Code is the Fragment View Java Class! Where I have put a Listener for the Button.

```
public class F_three extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//TODO Auto-generated method stub
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.f3,container,false);

Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startb);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now in the main class which is called on click of the button I've put the layout of an XML which is in Absolute View !

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
```

so the Layout main2.xml >>> Has absolute View ! But when I click the button it shows a Linear view.
the background becomes half and the contents shrinks up. Whereas I've placed everything properly in the absolute view.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: What is an "absolute view"?

Comment: Please show your XML layout files. Also how do you know "it shows a Linear view"? (I assume you mean `LinearLayout`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `AbsoluteLayout` has been deprecated since Android API 3.

So that means we shouldn't use it anymore, but use the other Layouts:

```
 - RelativeLayout
 - FrameLayout
 - DrawerLayout
 - LinearLayout
```

`AbsoluteLayout` needs someone to define actual dimensions, mostly, making it hard to maintain unlike other Layouts.

To achieve almost the same effect as in `AbsoluteLayout`, you could use `LinearLayout` or any other custom Layout.

---

```
Open for Correction, as Always!

Regards,
Edward Quixote.
```

Comment: Thanks for the Info @Edward Quixote ! :) It cleared my doubt !